# Do not render anything (think its bcs of shaders)

Tags: opengl, rendering

My opengl program renders nothing. I think the problem is coming from my shaders. Can someone tell me what's wrong, or if there is nothing wrong, tell me from where the problem could come from?

***Fragment shader:***

```
#version 330 core
in vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D image;
uniform vec3 spriteColor;

void main()
{  
    color = vec4(spriteColor, 1.0) * texture(image, TexCoords);
}
```

***Vertex Shader***

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 vertex;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 text;

out vec2 TexCoords;
uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
void main()
{
    TexCoords = text;
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(vertex, 1.0);
}
```

***The function I use to sent data to shaders :***

```
void SpriteRenderer::initRenderData()
{

GLfloat taille = 1.0f;
taille /= 2;

int m_tailleCoordTextureBytes = 72 * sizeof(float);
int m_tailleVerticesBytes = 108 * sizeof(float);

    GLuint VBO;
    GLfloat verticesTmp[] = {-taille, -taille, -taille,   taille, -taille, -taille,   taille, taille, -taille,     // Face 1
                       -taille, -taille, -taille,   -taille, taille, -taille,   taille, taille, -taille,     // Face 1

                       taille, -taille, taille,   taille, -taille, -taille,   taille, taille, -taille,       // Face 2
                       taille, -taille, taille,   taille, taille, taille,   taille, taille, -taille,         // Face 2

                       -taille, -taille, taille,   taille, -taille, taille,   taille, -taille, -taille,      // Face 3
                       -taille, -taille, taille,   -taille, -taille, -taille,   taille, -taille, -taille,    // Face 3

                       -taille, -taille, taille,   taille, -taille, taille,   taille, taille, taille,        // Face 4
                       -taille, -taille, taille,   -taille, taille, taille,   taille, taille, taille,        // Face 4

                       -taille, -taille, -taille,   -taille, -taille, taille,   -taille, taille, taille,     // Face 5
                       -taille, -taille, -taille,   -taille, taille, -taille,   -taille, taille, taille,     // Face 5

                       -taille, taille, taille,   taille, taille, taille,   taille, taille, -taille,         // Face 6
                       -taille, taille, taille,   -taille, taille, -taille,   taille, taille, -taille};      // Face 6


    GLfloat coordtextures[] = {0, 0,   1, 0,   1, 1,     // Face 1
                           0, 0,   0, 1,   1, 1,     // Face 1

                           0, 0,   1, 0,   1, 1,     // Face 2
                           0, 0,   0, 1,   1, 1,     // Face 2

                           0, 0,   1, 0,   1, 1,     // Face 3
                           0, 0,   0, 1,   1, 1,     // Face 3

                           0, 0,   1, 0,   1, 1,     // Face 4
                           0, 0,   0, 1,   1, 1,     // Face 4

                           0, 0,   1, 0,   1, 1,     // Face 5
                           0, 0,   0, 1,   1, 1,     // Face 5

                           0, 0,   1, 0,   1, 1,     // Face 6
                           0, 0,   0, 1,   1, 1};    // Face 6

    for (int i = 0; i < 72; i++)
    {
        m_coord_texture[i] = coordtextures[i];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 108; j++)
    {
        m_vertices[j] = verticesTmp[j];
    }



    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(m_vertices)+sizeof(m_coord_texture), 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, m_tailleVerticesBytes, m_vertices);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_tailleVerticesBytes, m_tailleCoordTextureBytes, m_coord_texture);


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);



    glGenVertexArrays(1, &this->quadVAO);

        glBindVertexArray(this->quadVAO);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

            // Accès aux vertices
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

            // Accès aux coord des textures
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
            glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), BUFFER_OFFSET(m_tailleVerticesBytes));


        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the data you have, it looks as if the second vertex pointer is wrong:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat),
                      BUFFER_OFFSET(m_tailleVerticesBytes));
```

The offset between uv-coordinates is set to 3 floats, but since you only provide two of them, it should be `2 * sizeof(GLfloat)`.

Comment: Fixed it ! thanks ! But my problem is unfortunatly still there. But i reread my code and found that i couldn't explain the use of  "uniform sampler2D image;" in my fragment shader. I set its value to 0 but i don't know why... I think that value should have the texture itself but i can't figure how to pass it ... Maybe you can explain why ... "ResourceManager::GetShader("sprite").Use().SetInteger("image", 0);"

Comment: The texture sampler has to be set to the texture unit where the texture is bound. See [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Binding_textures_to_samplers)

Comment: Thanks i understand it right now ! But i steel do not see what is the problem ... Anyone has already met that problem ?? Cause it renders nothing no error problem nothing ... Do not know where to start

Comment: I could have found a clue ! I changed the color with glclearcolor to blue and what i am seeing is my cube in black without textures and for every face of the cube i only have one of the two triangles ... But i can not figure out why ...

Comment: That you see only half of the faces might come from backface culling. You have different winding orders in your mesh.

Comment: You were right thanks i had an old gl option with a weird culling stuff, deleted it and finally had a full cube !! But i was still having the texture problem ... But i found the error: It was the extension , i wrote .png and was .jpg ... Stupid error i know ^^ but when you got no error message you do not know where to start. Thanks everyone anyway !!